# Issue While fetching bodyHTML using partID in Mailcore2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mailcore2

I tried fetching the bodyHTML using the following code

```
MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * op = [imapsession     fetchMessageAttachmentOperationWithFolder:folderName uid:uid partID:partId    encoding:MCOEncoding8Bit
```

And I got the bodyHTML with some unwanted extra code. The Html I got for one of the mail is

```
   <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;"></div><div>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org=
<br/>/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"&gt;
<br/>&lt;html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
<br/>&lt;head&gt;
<br/>&lt;meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8" /&gt;
<br/>&lt;meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width" /&gt;
<br/>&lt;meta http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Dedge" /&gt;
<br/>&lt;/head&gt;
<br/>&lt;body style=3D"-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; =
<br/>background: #EEEEEE; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-=
<br/>serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 22px; margin: 0; =
<br/>min-width: 100%; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100% !important" bgco=
<br/>lor=3D"#EEEEEE"&gt;&lt;style type=3D"text/css"&gt;
<br/>body {
<br/>width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -m=
<br/>s-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
<br/>}
<br/>.ExternalClass {
<br/>width: 100%;
<br/>}
<br/>.ExternalClass {
<br/>line-height: 100%;
<br/>}
<br/>#backgroundTable {
<br/>margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important; line-height: 100% !important=
<br/>;
<br/>}
<br/>img {
<br/>outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; widt=
<br/>h: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;
<br/>}
<br/>body {
<br/>color: #222222; font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: n=
<br/>ormal; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3;
<br/>}
<br/>body {
<br/>font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;
<br/>}
<br/>a:hover {
<br/>color: #222222 !important;
<br/>}
```

And I am not able to render it on the web view. But when I tried fetching the body using the following method

```
MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * opr = [imapsession fetchMessageOperationWithFolder:folderName uid:uid urgent:YES];
```

I got the proper body html and was able to render it on the webview .The html I got for the above method is:-

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 20px;"></div><div><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body style=
"-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background: #EEEEEE; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 22px; margin: 0; min-width: 100%; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100% !important"
bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body {
width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
line-height: 100%;
}
#backgroundTable {
margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;
}
img {
outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;
}
body {
color: #222222; font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3;
}
body {
font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;
}
a:hover {
color: #222222 !important;
}
```

Is there any parser or any other way to get the body html .Since I have to use the method using partID to fetch the bodyHTML.

Comment: What's the content type of the part?

Comment: The Mime type is "text/HTML"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was while fetching the message using part it always uses the MCOEncoding8Bit for encoding instead of that we have to give the encoding which we get while fetching the message as shown below.

```
for(MCOAbstractPart *abstractPart in multiAbstractPart.parts)
    {
MCOIMAPPart *part = (MCOIMAPPart *)abstractPart;
MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * op = [imapsession     fetchMessageAttachmentOperationWithFolder:folderName uid:uid partID:partId    encoding:part.encoding];
}
```